# How do I use Juju in a restricted network?

Tags: networking, internet, juju, proxy, restricted

I got a shiny new server in the lab and I want to use Juju.  I install juju, and juju-local just fine.  The juju bootstrap completes successfully but when I attempt a deploy a charm I get an error:

```
$ juju deploy ubuntu
ERROR Cannot access the charm store. Are you connected to the internet? Error details: Get https://store.juju.ubuntu.com/charm-info?charms=cs%3Atrusty%2Fubuntu: dial tcp 91.189.95.67:443: connection timed out
```

The error message indicates that the server does not have access to the Internet, so I checked and the server is in an isolated network. I can use proxies to get out to the Internet.

**How do I configure Juju to use a restricted network?**

Answer (score 4):

The error message for this problem was correct, the server was in restricted network and did not have access to the Internet.  The lab has a proxy server for http and https traffic.

The solution was to export `http_proxy`, `https_proxy`, and `no_proxy` environment variables on the Juju host server:

```
export http_proxy=http://squid.internal:3128
export https_proxy=https://squid.internal:3128
export no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1,10.0.3.1
```

After setting these environment variables the server was able to contact the charm store over port 443 and the charm deployed successfully.

The `no_proxy` variable was used to exclude servers from the proxy.  I excluded 10.0.3.1 because that is the local bridge created by Juju.

Answer (score 1):

The best my google-goo can offer is

- https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/models-config

Comment: Hi Vladmir, thanks for the answer - however it would be great to include the information from the resources instead of just the links in case the links were to 404 in the future.